# How do I download a js file in my storage tab?

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-console

Trying to download a js file in my storage. I can open it and see the contents on another window but I want to be able to download the file to my computer. How do I do that? I tried clicking the 3 dots on the right but it just gives me the options to add or delete a bucket

I also mean downloading it straight from the console, and not in my code.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of where you are stuck?

Comment: Hey, just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that sidebar on the right, click on File Location > Create new access token. This will create a url which you can download the file from. The, click on the newly generated access token. This will copy the url. Past it into a new tab and download!